# How to include files in gcc search path?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am installing pylibrabbitmq on ubuntu. But `amqp.h` is not in search path. It is in

'`/tmp/src/rabbit/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq`'.

How can I add this location to gcc search path?

Comment: -I option resposible for includes in gcc. http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.htm

Comment: I am running 'sudo gcc -I /tmp/src/rabbit/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq amqp.h'

Comment: But getting error! Is it fine?

Comment: -I takes folders, not header names. It's derictive where to search for source code. Please read manual:)

Comment: So i run 'sudo gcc -I /tmp/src/rabbit/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq' ????

Comment: Gives fatal error 'No input files'!!!

Comment: I don't think that you need to run gcc by hands, there are probably exist build script and configure script check it's options. You need dev package to setup it by hands, like 'sudo apt-get install librabbitmq-dev'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14142/discussion-between-varela-and-mjq)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

run

```
sudo gcc whatever.c -I/dir/*
```

where ampq.h should be in the folder *

Comment: I have run "sudo gcc -I/tmp/src/rabbit/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq". But it says, gcc: fatal error: no input files

Comment: -1: Even though OP is running Ubuntu, not every command there needs to be run via `sudo`.